# Understanding example 3 on pg. 369 in Dummit & Foote (3rd edition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, module-isomorphism

Here is the example:

$(3)$ In general,  $$ \mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n \cong \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z,$$where $d$ is the $g.c.d$ of the integers $m$ and $n.$ To see this, observe first that $$a \otimes b = a \otimes (b.1) = (ab) \otimes 1 = ab (1 \otimes 1),$$
from which it follows that $ \mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n$ is a cyclic group with $1 \otimes 1$ as generator. Since $m (1 \otimes 1) = m \otimes 1 = 0 \otimes 1= 0 $ and similarly $n (1 \otimes 1) = 1 \otimes n = 0,$ we have $d (1 \otimes 1) = 0,$ so the cyclic group has order dividing $d.$ The map \varphi: $ \mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n \rightarrow \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ defined by $\varphi(a \operatorname{mod}m, b \operatorname{mod}n) = ab \operatorname{mod} d$ is well defined since $d$ divides both $m$ and $n.$ It is clearly $\Bbb Z$-bilinear. The induced map $\Phi: \mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n \rightarrow \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$ from corollary 12 maps $1 \otimes 1$ to the element $1 \in \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z,$ which is an element of order $d.$ In particular $\mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n$ has order at least $d.$ Hence $1 \otimes 1$ is an element of order $d$ and $\Phi$ gives an isomorphism $$ \mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n \cong \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z.$$

**My questions are:**

1- How can I prove that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism? what is the definition of it? what is a good candidate for the definition of its inverse?

2- In the fourth line, why we can move the $b$ between the first and second coordinate of the tensor product? I know that this is correct for elements of ring $R$ only i.e. $(rm) \otimes n = m \otimes (rn)$ but I do not know that we can also move the $m,n$'s.

3- Why $d(1 \otimes 1) = 0$?

4-why the cyclic group has order $d$ ? Is not the order of the group is its cardinality? why our group has $d$ elements? I can not see any proof to that.

5- Why $d$ divides both $m$ and $n$ leads to that the map $\varphi$ is well defined?

Answers for those queries will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid images; they cannot be searched, and screen readers often cannot handle them. If you must include them, then you should add descriptive text to make them accessible. And if you are going to refer to a book, shouldn’t you take care not to mangle the author’s name?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so sorry about that. is there a way to turn images directly to text without typing? this will save a lot of time and effort to me.

Comment: If there were an automatic way of turning images into text, then there wouldn’t be an accessibility problem with using images instead of text, nor would there be a problem searching images: you would just run searches through the text-converters. So... no, there isn’t. Some effort on your part is not out of place when you are asking for help.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you are correct .... I will edit my question ... I am so sorry again.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am just afraid that I may write wrong things and also I am very slow in typing. So just give me some time to do that.

Comment: It is understandable why you would prefer to just post an image. I explained why that really corresponds to you making your post less friendly to readers, less accessible, and less useful to the community. When given the choice between doing less work and more work, most of us choose less work, all things being equal; I was informing you of the consequences to the community of that choice in this case, and why not all things are equal relative to the choice.

Comment: Thank you for clarification@ArturoMagidin

Comment: @hard I haven't used it before, but [mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) can turn images into LaTeX.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn oh really thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Dummit and Foote give the definition of $\Phi$ in the same sentence as it first appears. Explicitly, they define $\Phi : (\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z) \to \mathbb Z / d \mathbb Z$ by $\Phi[(1 + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z)] = 1 + d \mathbb Z.$

2.) Each of the quotient rings is an abelian group  (i.e., a $\mathbb Z$-module), and the tensor product is considered with respect to $\mathbb Z,$ so it is $\mathbb Z$-bilinear. Check the definition of $- \otimes_{\mathbb Z} -.$

3.) By definition, $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n,$ hence in particular, there exist integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $mk + n \ell = d.$ Consequently, we have that $d + m \mathbb Z = n \ell + m \mathbb Z$ so that $$d[(1 + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z)] = (d + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z) = (n \ell + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z).$$ Can you see why this is equal to $0?$

> We have that $$(n \ell + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z) = n[(\ell + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z)] = (\ell + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (n + n \mathbb Z) = 0.$$

4.) Once you have shown that $(1 + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z)$ generates $(\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z)$ as an abelian group, it suffices to find the order of $(1 + m \mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1 + n \mathbb Z).$ (Why?) By (3.) above, it is $d.$

5.) Consider the map $\varphi : (\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z) \to \mathbb Z / d \mathbb Z$ defined by $\varphi(a + m \mathbb Z, b + n \mathbb Z) = ab + d \mathbb Z.$ Given that $a + m \mathbb Z = a' + m \mathbb Z$ and $b + n \mathbb Z = b' + n \mathbb Z,$ we must show that $ab + d \mathbb Z = a' b' + d \mathbb Z.$ By hypothesis, we have that $m \,|\, (a - a')$ and $n \,|\, (b - b')$ so that $a - a' = mk$ and $b - b' = n \ell$ for some integers $k$ and $\ell.$ Using these two identities, can you verify that $ab + d \mathbb Z = a' b' + d \mathbb Z$?

> Considering that $d \,|\, m$ and $d \,|\, n,$ we have that $ab + d \mathbb Z = a'b + d \mathbb Z$ and $a' b + d \mathbb Z = a' b' + d \mathbb Z$ so that $ab + d \mathbb Z = ' b' + d \mathbb Z,$ and $\varphi$ is well-defined.

---

One other way to see this is to prove the following more general fact.

**Fact.** If $R$ is a commutative unital ring with ideals $I$ and $J,$ then $$\frac R I \otimes_R \frac R J \cong \frac R {I + J}.$$

To prove this, you might show that for any $R$-module $M,$ we have that $(R / I) \otimes_R M \cong M / IM.$ I believe that you have already proved this in a [separate exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021359/390180). From this, it follows that $(R / I) \otimes_R (R / J) \cong (R / J) / [I(R / J)].$ It suffices to prove that $I(R / J) = (I + J)/J.$

For our particular case, we have that $R = \mathbb Z,$ $I = m \mathbb Z,$ and $J = n \mathbb Z.$ In a Euclidean domain $R,$ we have that $aR + bR = \gcd(a, b)R.$ Considering that $\mathbb Z$ is a Euclidean domain, it follows that $m \mathbb Z + n \mathbb Z = d \mathbb Z.$ Putting this all together gives the desired result.

Comment: What is the inverse of $\Phi,$ how it is defined so that I get an isomorphism?

Comment: [Cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760471/390180). Compare the (canonical) isomorphism from this problem with $\Phi.$

Comment: In 3.) I do not see why you said this "Consequently, we have that $d + m \mathbb Z = n \ell + m \mathbb Z$ " ... could you elaborate please?

Comment: Use the definition of congruence modulo an ideal: if $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R,$ then for any two elements $x, y \in R,$ we have that $x + I = y + I$ if and only if $(x - y) + I = 0_R + I$ if and only if what?

Comment: $x-y \in I$ but what are $I$ and $x,y$?

Comment: It seems like you I am losing an idea you are using. for example, in your first spoiler, I do not know why what before the last equality equals zero i.e., why $(nl + m\mathbb Z)\otimes_{\mathbb z}(1 + n\mathbb Z) =0 $?

Comment: Oh I think I see the answer to my last question now.  Is not it because $1 \otimes n(times any thing) = 0$?

Comment: I did not get at all the idea you are using in your second spoiler here "Considering that $d \,|\, m$ and $d \,|\, n,$ we have that $ab + d \mathbb Z = a'b + d \mathbb Z$ and $a' b + d \mathbb Z = a' b' + d \mathbb Z$ " ... could you elaborate this please?

Comment: Your second-to-last comment above is exactly the point. As for your last comment (and the comment above that), I suggest you go back and review congruence modulo an ideal. Again, what does it mean that $ab + d \mathbb Z = a' b + d \mathbb Z?$ This is also an equivalence relation, so if $ab \sim a' b$ and $a' b \sim a' b',$ then what can you say about $ab$ and $a' b'$?

Comment: Sorry for my disturbing, but I do not know how to show that $\not\exists \text{positive integer} k<d$ s.t. $k(\bar{1}\otimes\bar{1})\neq 0$.